# Форматный вывод без UTC в Golang

Tags: golang, datetime

Мне нужно сделать форматный вывод в golang для типа `time.Date`. Вывод принимает вид для `time.Date.String()`:

`2018-07-10 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Мне же нужно:

`2018-07-10 00:00:00`

Я могу сделать тип, который реализует нужный мне вывод с методом String. Но здесь возникает закономерный вопрос: может есть более простой метод сделать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://tip.golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

https://tip.golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hXnJSO11bV2

Comment: Да, я с этим разобрался. Но вопрос, почему в golang используется конкретная дата `2006-01-02 15:04:05`, а не, например, формат: `%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%S`, как это делается, например, в питоне? Есть ли для этого причины какие-нибудь?

Comment: Такое решение приняли создатели языка. Мне лично нравится, так как формат получается самоочевидный. Запомнить легко: 1 месяц, 2 день, 3 часа вечера, 4 минуты, 5 секунд, (200)6 года, в зоне +0700.